# set the center of a embedded map (google map) to a specific location

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I'm trying to use this map in a website and I am using the next piece of HTML code to add it.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zkqAm4_X6ia8.kj6iIDUiDRdc&hl=es" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

My problem is that I want the embedded map to show the Utrecht area only, but I can't figure out how to change the center of the embedded map. I know that the parameter z= will set the zoom level. I've tried the center= parameter as specified in the documentation, but it does not seem to work

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters

does anybody how to set the center?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can pass the lat and long by adding `&ll=LAT, LONG`

ex:

```
&ll=40.7127, -74.0059
```

Just add it to the end of the link in `src`

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zkqAm4_X6ia8.kj6iIDUiDRdc&hl=es&ll=40.7127, -74.0059" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tt9bzcnt/)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. For more parameters: http://asnsblues.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the lat lang to the iframe src attribute like center=lat,lng if you are using google EMBED.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below for map options

```
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.1, 122)
```

I had to experiment  with variations of LatLng to get the desired centered position,

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help  width="100%" height="600, I inserted a google map and when i change the screen length the map will adjust depending of the screen you see the map and the pointer will be in the center always hope it helps you.