# How can I centre a map on a location in iframe embedd

Tags: mymaps

How can I centre a map created in Google MyMap when using an iframe embedd?

I have followed the instructions in this answer [set the center of a embedded map (google map) to a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736481/set-the-center-of-a-embedded-map-google-map-to-a-specific-location) but there must be something I am doing wrong because when I add it throws up an error on my website.

```
<div class="<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/5/embed?mid=163MCh2-2Ccq7CFENK2NBWtj7UYVGrHeW&amp;t=k&z=16&amp" width="640" height="480"></iframe></div>">
```

I would like to add the following lat/long:

40.7127, -74.0059

Many thanks in advance for community assistance - as I only have a high school education, and get easily confused, if someone would be kind enough to paste the complete code above with the lat/long code added I would be hugely grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your HTML, you put your iframe in a class of the div and the open-close quotes are incorrect as well

```
<div class="<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/5/embed?mid=163MCh2-2Ccq7CFENK2NBWtj7UYVGrHeW&amp;t=k&z=16&amp" width="640" height="480"></iframe></div>">
```

The following should have the desired output

```html
<div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/5/embed?mid=163MCh2-2Ccq7CFENK2NBWtj7UYVGrHeW&amp;t=k&z=16&amp&ll=40.7127, -74.0059" width="640" height="480"></iframe></div>
```

I added the lat and long given in the answer you linked

Comment: Thank you so much - really appreciate you taking the time to share and help me out in this way!

Comment: Glad to be of some help and hope it worked out for you